# Mouse not working correctly on Mac login screen

Tags: macos, usb, mouse, login

For some reason when my mac is at the login screen, moving my external USB mouse will cause the cursor to only move up and down. Once I am logged in, the mouse functions normally. Does anyone know the reason/fix?

Steps I have taken:

- Reset SMC/NVRAM
- Reinstalled OS
- Tried another USB Port

Late 2013 15" MacBook Pro running Yosemite 10.10.3

with iHome wireless USB mouse.

I tested it and mouse works fine without problems on my Windows PC.

Comment: What type of mouse is it?  Logitech?

Comment: It's an iHome wireless USB. IIRC it worked fine prior to Yosemite.

Comment: can you look back in the log after the boot started to see how it is identified (In the Console log)

Comment: A mouse is pretty basic tech and there's not much requried in terms of power.  5V is more than enough to operate the LED and camera inside your mouse (yes, it's a camera!)  

The first thing to check is if that mouse works on another computer.  If so, then you are narrowing down your issue.  Next, if you have another mouse, see if that works on your Mac.

Comment: @Allan good logic with one flaw. It works after the boot process is completed?

Comment: mouse works fine without problems on my Windows PC

Comment: @Buscar웃  The logic is sound.  If the problem manifests on other computers then it probably requires some specialized HID driver to function properly.  The generic one that gets loaded as the OS boots isn't cutting it.  Additionally, there may be a faulty USB bus on the Mac.  The idea here is to ensure the functionality of the device before proceeding with diagnostics on the computer.

Comment: @Allan, have to disagree, first thing it happens is self test, followed by hardware identification, followed by correct drivers are loaded, not generic. My guess is it does not ID the mouse correctly initially, and therefore loads the generic driver. In any case I would check that driver and update it.

Comment: @Buscar웃  Sorry that you disagree, but it tries to detect the hardware, if it cannot find it, it loads a generic driver.  Case in point, Logitech.  None of my extra buttons work until I load the setpoint utility is loaded, and that happens AFTER login.  Given that iHome is a very small vendor in the mouse "space" it would be unlikely that Apple has built in kernel support for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming this is a USB mouse with a cord? I have seen issues with those not recognizing properly until login when connected through the USB ports on a keyboard, or on laptops. I've always accounted it to the mouse needing more voltage than the USB port is delivering until the user is logged in. This seems to be the case with older mice more often than newer ones.

Comment: It is  iHome wireless USB. IIRC! Does your experience still applies ?

Comment: It depends, after googling "iHome wireless USB mouse" it looks like your mouse might be a bit older. I'd be willing to bet that the receiver is using more voltage (probably 5v) which is getting getting picked up by the OS until the computer logs in. The instances I've seen this problem occur have been with older Mice all over 5 years old on new machines. For example Microsoft mouse (2010) will recongnize on 2012 Mac Pro, but not the new Mac Pro. Can you try a newer mouse?

Comment: I found this article on the USB power matter. https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204377 There are a few things in there you can check. You might also want to check and make sure there aren't any drivers you have to install from the manufacturer, or if there are drivers installed, see if there are newer ones that are Yosemite compatible.

Comment: That Voltage logic would not cut it, it works after the boot process is completed.

Comment: I just tried a Logitech M705 I found around the office, and it doesn't have this issue. I guess it is voltage.

Comment: I can't see how voltage would be the problem.  A USB mouse draws no more than 50mA or less of power.  That's 10% of what the USB port is capable of 500mA (half an amp).    If you want to check power, plug in a USB Hard Drive.  If it power up, power is good on the Mac side of things.

Chances are, you have a mouse with a faulty or incompatible (with Yosemite) driver.

Comment: @Allan here I have to agree with you, it is not possible the Voltage is a problem initially and then it fixes itself after full log in.

Comment: I will test the driver theory after work today.